# Xubuntu 23.10 ISO Verification

Tags: xubuntu, iso

I'm new to the community and have a question re verification of my Xubuntu 23.10 iso image that i downloaded via torrent link from their site.
I did the iso verification on my macbook as per these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview , and it turns out the desired "Good signature" and "xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso: OK" at the end, but two things confuse me,

1. unlike in the tutorial, I only receive one RSA key and no DSA key for the SHA256SUM.xxx files
2. I wonder what the "[ unknown]" that appears before "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com" after the key fingerprint line is supposed to mean?

Would really appreciate your 2cents on this, just to confirm I did everything right and the ISO is good.

Heres the section copied from my Terminal

```shell
me$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg.txt SHA256SUMS.txt
gpg: Signature made Thu 12 Oct 14:13:39 2023 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
me$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
me$ gpg --keyid-format long --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0x843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
pub   rsa4096/D94AA3F0EFE21092 2012-05-11 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid                 [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>
```

```shell
me$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg.txt SHA256SUMS.txt
gpg: Signature made Thu 12 Oct 14:13:39 2023 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
me$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.txt 2>&1 | grep OK
xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Thanks!
Edit: thanks for the formatting suggestions!
Edit2: seems like the .gpg file itself is not signed? When I try to identify it alone it returns:

```
me$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg.txt
gpg: no signed data
gpg: can't hash datafile: No data
```

Comment: Strict usage of gpg means that there is a complete chain of trusted signatures/keys from the creator of the file to the user (you). This is not the case here (very difficult to achieve), but it is as good as possible and I would say 'good enough', if you downloaded the files from an official Ubuntu or Ubuntu family flavour's web site via http**s**.

Comment: Thank you! So I did nothing wrong in the verification process? I downloaded it through the torrent release from https://xubuntu.org/release/23-10/#show-all (so yes, http**s**)